# Fetching data with wrong column with eloquent relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many

I have two models Country and State.
Relationship between them is as given below:
Country:

```
public function States()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\State');
}
```

State:

```
public function Country()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}
```

Now, I want fetch states that belongs to the country in show method.

```
public function show(Country $country)
{
    $states = $country->States()->get();
    dd($states);
}
```

But, here it throws an error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'states.country_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `states` where `states`.`country_id` = 11 and `states`.`country_id` is not null)

It is right that country_id does not exist because it is named as countries_id
as the name of table for Country is countries.

Please help how to solve this error.

Comment: states.country_id references to table states and column country_id, if you want to reference to Country table use country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreign key` are not matching, add foreign key column as `second` parameter on your `relationship` function.

```
public function States()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\State','countries_id');
}
```

By `convention`, Eloquent take the `"snake case"` name of the owning model and `suffix` it with `_id` as `foreign key`. That's why it was getting `country_id` instead of `countries_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Add foreign key to the relationship definition:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\State', 'countries_id');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many